# Group Summary only on last level

Tags: c#, gridview, devexpress

I have a GridView and I added 2 Summary Group, the problem is the summary are shown
twice, for every single row. I only want the last one. I post an image to
ilustrate what i want(in the image the summary that i want is marked in red).
Thanks.
[GroupSummary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLuZw.png)

Comment: Have you added your summary requirement in <GroupSummary> tag of Gridview?

Comment: I really don't understand the question. Please, can explain it for me? Thnaks.